# Typescript: valueOf object arithmetics typing

Tags: javascript, typescript

Id like to wrap a number inside an wrapper and still be able to use the object as member of an native arithmetics (`+`, `-`, `<`, etc.) calculation. I know this is possible [in plain js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf) and was wondering if such code can be statically typed at all, or if this is against the nature of ts.

```
class A<T> {
  constructor(public prop: T) {

  }
  valueOf() {
    return this.prop
  }
}

let num = new A(2)
console.log(num + 3) // Err
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gWAFDWsA9gHYQAuATgK7An5kAUADhQEYgCWw0DZ+DAXNEQBKdNmy4AvuOgA3MCAoBTAPIAzOiMw5c0MopIUyhaCQAWbCADpuvaVKz3sIfdEIUAttAC8rxQHc4OgAmIWwCYnxnSxB8AHM6N08AamgAZlCsbCA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say `num as unknown as number` which would recast num as a number or call `num.valueOf()`.

I would recommend using `.valueOf` since it is more explicit that you are converting an object to a number.

Here is another answer by MaximilianMairinger using unions:

```
class InternalA<T> {
  constructor(public prop: T) {

  }
  valueOf() {
    return this.prop
  }
}


interface A<T> { new<T>(prop: T): InternalA<T> & T }
const A = InternalA as A<number>

let num = new A(2)
console.log(num + 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I agree using `Object#valueOf` is more explicit though thats not really what I was asking for... After a bit of playing around I found [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AXApgJ3mEBBAPAFQD5oBvAWAChppgB7eCRVAV2ERtQAoAHJgIxACWwaF1Q0uALmh4AlCQoUqAX0XQAbpibIA8gDMOcspSrRUyRE3TREACwEQAdKPGqV5NwvKIAnl2TQsaABeEmh4ZAB3fAJuMUlpGSkEFHRMXEJoADJpaDdaekQA4LgkNAxsaEgAzxBzMKYAW2LwiICOACYZCnyIGlqHEBoAcw54RugAamgAZi7yIA) to work, event though this has some drawbacks, as that `Number#toExponential` is declared but cannot be called during runtime

Comment: If you could add this to your answere id be happy to accept it

Comment: Added your solution with a little modification (using a generic interface rather than a type)

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported by TypeScript yet: [Allow wrapped values to be used in place of primitives.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2361)

You can hack around this a bit:

```
class A {
  constructor(public prop: number) {
  }
  otherMethod() { }
  valueOf() {
    return this.prop
  }
}

type AsNumber<T> = number & T;

let num: AsNumber<A> = <any>new A(2);
console.log(num + 3)
num.otherMethod();
```